# How do you write in JavaScript a empty key from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, key

Let's say you have the following JSON object

```
{"":"some text"}
```

How do you retrieve it in JavaScript?

```
json_in_var={"":"some text"}  
alert(json_in_var.)
```

I'm perplexed on this one, any help welcome!

Answer (score 20):

It's an syntax error to refer to it with

```
json_in_var.
```

However, you can access it like this:

```
json_in_var[""]
```

Answer (score 2):

Easily...

```
alert(json_in_var[""]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.keys()`:-

```
<script>
    var myObj, x;
    myObj = {"":"some text"};
    x = Object.keys(myObj)[0];
    x = myObj[x];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

I was able to solve this by using

```
alert(json_in_var.$t)
```

This is when retrieving Blogger feeds in json format. I am unsure if this  is proprietary.

Comment: There's nothing special about $t, it's a legal JavaScript name — if you were thinking about that.